# selecting a row from a dynamic table cell with jquery inside an ajax json function

Tags: jquery, ajax, button, dynamic, html-table

I am trying to identify a table row selected from a button inside a table cell that has been constructed from a string with jquery - using the button class as the selector.

There are a number of similar questions like mine here and I have adjusted my code accordingly and  I believe this should work but I'm wondering if there is some problem around dynamically building the html and therefore the table elements not being in the Dom tree. In other words it might not be possible.  I have separated the string line to make it easier to read.

```
function GetBooks(brand) {      
    $(function(){ 
    var mypath=brand;
        $.ajax({ 
            method: "GET", 
            url: "getrecords_ajax.php",
        data:{mypath:mypath},
        }).done(function( data ) { 
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            var string='<table id="mytable">';
            /* from result create a string of data and append to the div */  
            $.each( result, function( key, value ) {

string +="<tr><td>" +value['title']+ "</td><td>" +value['authors']+ "</td><td> <button class=\"btnSelect\">Select</button> </td></tr>";
    
        }); 
            string += '</table>'; 
            $("#records").html(string);
        }); 
     });
}
```

the code to respond to the button click is:

```
$("#mytable").on('click','.btnSelect',function(){
            // get the current row
    alert("got inside click function");
            var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr"); 
     var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
    alert(col1); 
});
```

This doesn't work and the alert doesn't even trigger inside the onclick function indicating that it isnt even going there.

Answer (score 1):

You're attaching an event handler to `#mytable`, but `#mytable` is created dynamically. You really want to attach the event handler to an element that always exists, assuming `#records` is always there and never replaced

```
$("#records").on('click','#mytable .btnSelect',function(){
            // get the current row
    alert("got inside click function");
    var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr"); 
    var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text();
    alert(col1); 
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I'm not sure I understand it.  Do I need to create object(s) 'records' or define them somewhere?

Comment: who cares...it works! brilliant. Not sure how though.  What's going on here?

Comment: `records` is the id of an element in your html, I used a css seclector to identify it.

Comment: ah yes (I wrote that so long ago I'd forgotten it lol)